# Nativescript Run on Device IOS - dyld Library not loaded @rpath/Nativescript.framework

Tags: xcode, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Runs fine on emulator (pretty basic app, only a few changes to check deploy works etc before continue).

Throws this error

```
 dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/NativeScript.framework/NativeScript
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2F0F006E-3DC7-4017-A024-820AE0612E1D/mobileapp.app/mobileapp
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2F0F006E-3DC7-4017-A024-820AE0612E1D/mobileapp.app/Frameworks/NativeScript.framework/NativeScript: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2F0F006E-3DC7-4017-A024-820AE0612E1D/mobileapp.app/Frameworks/NativeScript.framework/NativeScript'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2F0F006E-3DC7-4017-A024-820AE0612E1D/mobileapp.app/Frameworks/NativeScript.framework/NativeScript: stat() failed with errno=25
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2F0F006E-3DC7-4017-A024-820AE0612E1D/mobileapp.app/Frameworks/NativeScript.framework/NativeScript: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2F0F006E-3DC7-4017-A024-820AE0612E1D/mobileapp.app/Frameworks/NativeScript.framework/NativeScript'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2F0F006E-3DC7-4017-A024-820AE0612E1D/mobileapp.app/Frameworks/NativeScript.framework/NativeScript: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2F0F006E-3DC7-4017-A024-820AE0612E1D/mobileapp.app/Frameworks/NativeScript.framework/NativeScript: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2F0F006E-3DC7-4017-A024-820AE0612E1D/mobileapp.app/Frameworks/NativeScript.framework/NativeScript'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2F0F006E-3DC7-4017-A024-820AE0612E1D/mobileapp.app/Frameworks/NativeScript.framework/NativeScript: stat() failed with errno=1
```

Any assistanced much appreciated, totally stumped.

That error is from Xcode.
the application builds and deploys however on run just hangs on first screen with that error.

Comment: Are you trying to launch the app from Xcode on your device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since paying for the Apple Developer Program it deployed without any issues. I can only (assume) that this was the issue.

Previously I was only using the free certificate provided.

Interested to hear issues others had.

Comment: It seems like that Apple restricted the usage of free certificates in combination with embedded frameworks....